# Automatically focus input element after creation in purescript-halogen

Tags: purescript, halogen

I'm using purescript-halogen to build a spreadsheet-like table (similar to [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/)). If you double-click a cell, an html input element is rendered as a child of the respective table cell (and no such element is rendered for all the other cells).

This works really well with halogen, except that I don't know how to automatically set the focus to the newly created input element.

I tried the `autofocus` attribute, but this only works for the first cell that is double-clicked. The JavaScript way to do it is by calling the `focus()` method on the new element, but I don't know how to call it after the DOM has been updated in halogen. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use an "initializer"? The function signature changed in the new version, but if you look up that name in the docs/examples, you should find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here is how I did it using Phil's `Initializer` hint:

Write a JavaScript function that actually focuses the element.

```
exports.setFocusImpl = function(elemId) {
  return function() {
    document.getElementById(elemId).focus();
  };
};
```

FFI it.

```
foreign import data FOCUS :: !

foreign import setFocusImpl :: forall e. Fn1 String (Eff (focus :: FOCUS | e) Unit)

setFocus :: forall e. String -> Eff (focus :: FOCUS | e) Unit
setFocus = runFn1 setFocusImpl
```

And then use the `setFocus` function in the initializer.

```
H.input
[ A.id_ "inputField"
, A.Initializer do
    liftEff $ setFocus "inputField"
    pure DoNothing
] [ ]
```

Note that I'm using an old version of halogen where the signature is still the old one ([definition of `Initializer` in 30e8b2c7](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/30e8b2c7174a1eeda73f67cc42c739ca24a1e218/src/Halogen/HTML/Attributes.purs#L112)).

Comment: this solution requires assigning ids to nodes which complicates dynamic interface with multiple replicas. Isolation is not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

The mothod which is described here is a bit outdated. It is not necessary to write the foreign focus function. It exists already in the Web.HTML.HTMLElement library. I describe the updated method in my blog post here: [Focus Input Element](https://www.ersocon.net/articles/focus-input-element-in-halogen-purescript%7E802632d9-d9f4-4c37-96f9-aaf920d8c599)